# Convert date to device timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm parsing a JSON from my server, one of the values is a date like this: **2013-01-21 18:22:35 +00000**

My problem is how to transform this date to the local time like **2013-01-21 12:22:35 -0600**

I need to transform the date to other format?

Thanks!

**EDIT.**

Using the @Gabriele Petronella solution:

```
NSString * yourJSONString = @"2013-01-21 18:22:35 +0000";

NSTimeZone* localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSString* localAbbreviation = [localTimeZone abbreviation];

NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourJSONString];

NSTimeZone *timezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:localAbbreviation];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timezone];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate]);
```

Everything works fine!

Comment: You don't *convert* the NSDate object to local time, you *present* the date in local time, using NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `NSDateFormatter` to read the date from a `NSString`, then you can display the date changing the timezone using another (possibly the same) `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSString * yourJSONString = @"2013-01-21 18:22:35 +0000";
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle
 ];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];    
NSDate * aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourJSONString];

NSTimeZone * timezone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Chicago"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timezone];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate);
```

Please note that the timezone is just a matter of **display**, whereas the `NSDate` object is just an abstraction to represent the date and it is independent by its displaying.

Comment: Gabriele, your solution worked fine for me, I just made a few changes, I edited my initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]; 
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSString *myCurrentDeviceDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```